# compare two arrays in order

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare, matching

I thought this would be pretty simple, but I seem to be getting things mixed up, and I haven't found anything on stackoverflow that quite matches my question.

I'm trying to write a function that can compare two arrays of file names to make sure their values match. They need to actually match in their position as well, so the order is crucial. In other words:

```
array1 = ["file1.html", "file2.html", "file3.html", "file4.html"]
array2 = ["file1.html", "file2.html", "file4.html", "file3.html"]
```

I would want a comparison between these two arrays to return as false, because of the difference in order (even though both arrays actually include the same values). I tried something like this:

```
matching = true
names1 = array1.map { |x| File.basename(x)}
names2 = array2.map { |x| File.basename(x)}
    names1.each_with_index { |file,index|
        if file != names2[index]
            matching = false
        end
    }
return matching
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, more foolproof way of comparing arrays in this way? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `array1 == array2`? I suspect it does the pairwise compare you seek.

Comment: JFYI, you have `array1` twice.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-3D-3D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything of the sort. Default array equality operator compares arrays with order

```
array1 = %w[file1.html file2.html file3.html file4.html]
array2 = %w[file1.html file2.html file4.html file3.html]
array3 = %w[file1.html file2.html file3.html file4.html]

array1 == array2 # => false
array1 == array3 # => true
```

Example with comparing mapped values (if you have full paths in your arrays)

```
array1.map{|a| File.basename(a)} == array2.map{|a| File.basename(a) }
# or, as @mudasobwa would suggest
[array1, array2].map{|a| a.map(&File.method(:basename)) }.reduce(:==)
```

<sup>Use the last one if and only if a) you understand it completely and b)
 you think it's a good idea.</sup>

Comment: haha wow I was definitely overthinking this. Thank you so much for such a quick and concise reply!

Comment: @lumos: my pleasure. For the future, post actually valid runnable ruby (properly formatted too). What you have there won't even parse. It's miracle how you didn't get any downvotes.

Comment: This was copied as is from Sublime Text (I just renamed the arrays), and it runs fine both in Terminal and within the Sublime console...can I ask what exactly is incorrect, or not parsing?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev or c) you are mudasobwa

Comment: I am thinking about providing a PR to Rails team to monkey-patch `Array` to provide `map_map` method doing that intermediate mapping for nested arrays :-P

Comment: @lumos: actually, I was wrong. it's parseable, but still it will fail: `undefined local variable or method 'file1'`

Comment: @mudasobwa: "or c) you are mudasobwa" - you mean that a) and b) don't apply to you? :trollface:

Comment: Sure a) and b) don’t apply, I am confused you asking.